# Clutch issue Seat Leon

Tags: noise, clutch, manual-transmission, seat, seat-leon

Today I have noticed that every time I press the clutch it makes a loud sound- as if you are pressing a manual on/off button (not sure how else the explain the sound)
I stopped driving it just in case it is an indicator that something is really wrong, what could it be?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If the noise only occurs when you press the pedal, this is usually a sign the throwout bearing is going (or has gone) bad.

The throwout bearing comes in contact with the clutch arms to disengage the pressure plate and allow the friction disk to spin freely. The only time it comes in contact (or should come in contact) with the arms is when you press the pedal.

As far as replacement, you have to separate the engine and transmission. If you need to replace it, it's a good time to just replace the entire clutch because the major expense of labor is already paid for, so it makes fiscal sense.